Handle objects with binary data properties in Web API
I have these two EF Core entities in .NET 8, which has a mix of varchar and varbinary columns in SQL Server:
public class Collection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

I would like to be able to migrate a Collection between different environments.
If I POST to a Collection from one environment to another, how to bundle and unpack it? Convert byte arrays to base64 and POST the entire collection as JSON, or is there a more efficient way of handling this?

What do you mean by "environment"?

@AgentFire Different instances of my application, each with their own app service, sql database etc. I would like to migrate data between them over HTTP.

As I figure it, your question is one that asks "how to efficiently send a C# DTO object over a network".
Sometimes it would be dependent on what you mean by "efficient", but if I had to guess, then you might mean you need the total bytes of the transfer to be as small as possible, while making the entire serialization and deserialization at least a bit comfortable.
For that I would suggest looking into ProtoBuf (protobuf-net library), as it serializes objects into a compact byte array (but not human readable, where as JSON is quite human readable, but has considerably bigger size). However, it takes some time to set up initially.
There are also ways to create moderately compact database dumps (even of choice tables), but that's more manual approach, and depends on the database.

Thanks, you got it right, poorly phrased by me. Something like protobuf is definitely what I'm after functionality wise. I've only heard of it so far but just as you say I have a feeling that I'll be using a tank to kill a mosquito with that. If you have any alternatives feel free to suggest.

Think I found an option: https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp

@filur that works too ^^
